# how to get UIImage from SKSpriteNode

Tags: sprite-kit, uiimage

I've got a problem getting UIImage object from SKSpriteNode i.e i can get it, but after changing SKSpriteNode's properties like blendMode, colorBlendFactor and color, the texture property stays unchanged.
here's an example:

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "fishka")
sprite.blendMode = .alpha
sprite.colorBlendFactor = 1
sprite.color = UIColor.red
let fishka = UIImage(cgImage: (sprite.texture?.cgImage())!)
```

that's what i get:

[result after converting to UIImage (fishka)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQyE1.png) and 
[image in SKSpriteNode object (sprite)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOuFE.png)

please, how can i get an UIImage object with picture as in SKSpriteNode?

thank you

UPDATE

here is another code which uses CGContext to get desired result

```
let img = UIImage(named: "fishka")!
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: img.size.width, height: img.size.height)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
img.draw(in: rect)
ctx?.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
ctx?.setAlpha(1)
ctx?.setBlendMode(.sourceAtop)
ctx?.fill(rect)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
```

and now image looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5uSF.png)

tuning **ctx?.setAlpha()** is not a solution because i want a bright red color keeping volumetric [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQyE1.png)

is there any other solution?

thank you*2

Comment: You are seeing the expected behavior. When you set a sprite node's color, the color you specify blends with the texture's color and is applied to the sprite. Setting a sprite's color does not change the texture's color. If you update your question with what you're trying to achieve, such as why you need to create an image from a sprite node, someone might be able to provide a helpful solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SKView.texture(from:SKNode)` to achieve what you want.

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "fishka")
sprite.blendMode = .alpha
sprite.colorBlendFactor = 1

sprite.color = UIColor.red
var fishka = UIImage?
autoreleasepool{
    fishka = scene!.view!.texture(from:sprite)
}
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what i need:  view.texture(from:sprite)
 Thank you!